17-year-old sent to a mental institute for beating another boy
Okay, I've been searching Google for hours trying to find this movie and just cannot found it, so I wanted to try here. It wasn't popular at my time, so that's not helping either.
Taking place: inside a mental institute for teenagers. 
Main Character: I don't know the actor, but he was a white and 17 years old and sent to the mental institute for beating a boy on his sports team half to death. During the movie, he admits to his psychiatrist that his father beat him as a kid, and the boy he beat up was teasing him about that fact.
Other Characters: 

There's the boys roommate (I think) who looked to be somewhat hispanic, who's also in the institution.
A girl with short hair seemed to be in the institute because she wanted to take her own life. She eventually become the main love interest of the main character.
A girl with long black hair who usually is wearing all black as well. She isn't afraid to smart off to anyone.
A big guy who is the bully of the institute, always poking fun at all of the other people in there. He brings up why they're there and how messed up they are, acting as if he's better than the rest of them.
A spunky guy who becomes best friends with the main character. He's the funnier one, and is usually cracking jokes while things are going bad around him. He gets the main character pot a little after they first met and smoked it in the bathroom. He also was turning 18 soon, and before he was going to leave the institute in a few days, he cut the throat of one of the security guards, almost taking out his adams apple.
The dean of the mental hospital. He's a tall, black male with a wife and kids. He interviews everyone in the institute, wondering if he's helping any of them at all. He's also the only psychiatrist in the movie and is in group with the teenagers a few times.

Memorable scenes:

The main character gets his hands on the security guards keys and is now allowed into everyone's room and can escape the mental institute.
The ending scene, where the main character lets himself out of the institute and runs to the nearby bus station as a means of escaping. Before he reaches it, he stops, realizing he is not ready to go and needs to stay there and get better. After a moment of sitting there, he turns around and heads back to the institute.

This movie is shot from an outsiders point of view, not really taking a first person story view to the entire movie.
If anyone knows the name of this movie please tell me! I really loved this movie and wanted to try to purchase it.

+5 for a very description question, bravo.

I believe this is the movie "manic" with Joseph Gordon-Levitt. I saw it a couple of years ago and it sounds like that movie.
Yep, i just checked Wikipedia, that's definitely the one.

Please try to add the excerpt from Wikipedia which you think that matches OP's description.

from wikipedia: After brutally beating another teen with a baseball bat during a baseball game, Lyle Jensen, an impulsive and aggressive teen, is admitted to the juvenile psychiatric ward of a hospital along with other troubled teens

Probably you thought I was the down-voter but I wasn't. I was trying to tell you that adding excerpt from Wikipedia and providing link in your answer would be much more informative and fetches you more upvotes.

oh no, to be honest i really haven't figured out this website yet, between the voting and the reputation changes and the different classifications of members... i'm a little lost.  but to be fair i haven't really tried to figure it out
